# How do I float my image tag in ruby on rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to float logo.png to the left but it won't work.  Here's my Rails code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Pragprog Books Online Store</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag   "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag    "application", "data-turbolinks-track"  => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>">
    <div id="banner">
        <%= image_tag ("logo.png") %>         <----------- can't move this thing!
        <%= @page_title || "Pragmatic Bookshelf"%>
    </div>
    <div id ="columns">
        <div id="side">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www......">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www......">Questions</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www......">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www......">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```css
#banner {
    background: #9c9;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    font: small-caps 40px/40px "Times New Roman", serif;
    color: #282;
    text-align:  center;
    img {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

I'm futzing around with the code and I can't seem to manipulate the image at all.  Looked around for a missed  or something but can't find a thing.  What am I missing?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Ruby and I don't think it doesn't have anything to do with Ruby on Rails either. It's pure CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#banner {
background: #9c9;
padding: 10px;
border-bottom: 2px solid;
font: small-caps 40px/40px "Times New Roman", serif;
color: #282;
text-align:  center;
}
#banner img {
    float: left;
}
#banner h1 {
    text-align:center
}
```

of course this is just an approximation, you'll need to adjust things, but take a look to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6czzt3hc/) to see how is it done and make your changes as needed

Answer (score 0):

The image tag has a default `display` style of `inline`, which will not float. You should change the `display` to `block` in your stylesheet. Also, set its `position` style to `relative` to allow the block to be "pushed around" inside of the `#banner` div:

```
#banner {
    background: #9c9;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    font: small-caps 40px/40px "Times New Roman", serif;
    color: #282;
    text-align:  center;
    img {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Sorry, you should also add `position: relative` so that the `img` should be free to `float` inside of the containing `#banner` div. I'll edit my answer.